# Generate Monthly Report using MYSQL with SUM function

Tags: php, html, mysql

Good day everyone!

I have trouble generating monthly report... here are the data(s).

id: 1
Name: John Doe
Time: 5 min. 00 sec.

id: 2
Name: John Doe
Time: 15 min. 00 sec.

id: 3
Name: Van Helsing
Time: 10 min. 00 sec.

the result is

John Doe
Total Time: 0 hr. 30 min.

it means the total of those three time was added  and that was not my target result.. it must be:

John Doe
Total Time: 20 min. 00 sec.

Van Helsing
Total Time: 10 min. 00 sec.

here's my query:

```
SELECT pd.firstname, pd.lastname, pd.middlename, SUM(p.hoursDiff) as totalHr, SUM(p.minDiff) as totalMin, SUM(p.secDiff) as totalSec
FROM request_pass_slip r
JOIN pass_slip p ON p.request_id=r.request_id
JOIN pds pd ON pd.info_id=r.info_id
WHERE YEAR(r.request_date)=2016 AND MONTH(r.request_date)=2 AND pd.emp_type='JO'
```

here's the code that causing error:

```
SUM(p.minDiff) as totalMin, SUM(p.secDiff) as totalSec
```

can anyone help me? Is just i'm out of options... I can't find the right query.

Comment: Add, as the last line, `GROUP BY pd.firstname, pd.lastname, pd.middlename`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want your results to be grouped by people, you need to use `GROUP BY`.

Add to your query at the end `GROUP BY pd.firstname, pd.lastname, pd.middlename`

Without it, the sum works on the entire result set

Comment: it works! but one problem arise... it's about seconds... after the test run I encounter 4 min. 76 sec. it must 5 min. 16 sec.